# JNI_OnLoad get Java caller package+class name

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is there a way to get Java package and classname from which native library was initialized from JNI_OnLoad? I want to reuse my native library in multiple Java projects and don't know in advance classname and package from where LoadLibrary("mynativelibrary") is called. Then I could use JNI RegisterNatives with dynamic classname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across the same problem recently. I ended up reusing the class (i.e. copying the code) which loads the native library and handles all callbacks into other projects keeping the original package name. If you make that class generic and use an interface for callbacks then it shouldn't have any dependency on the project and so can be used anywhere. Works well for me.

Comment: So basically your solution is to copy JNI interface Java class file into other projects but keep it in same package as before, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right. You could potentially package in a jar to avoid have multiple copies of the class in each project

Comment: Will accept, would be nice to get caller classname from JNI though, but it's probably not possible.